# Why won't \hspace work?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, indentation

I'm trying to get a block of text to be aligned 2.55cm from the left of the page. I'm sure there's a better way of doing this, but it would be nice to get an answer anyway.

When I type:

`\hspace{2.55cm} text text text text text text ... text`

I get an output that has the first line 2.55cm from the left but the following lines are aligned with the left of the page, naturally. So I tried using the `\hspace{2.55cm}` command at the point in the text where I want there to be an indent (i.e. the start of every line in the output). But when I do this, I get the same output with only the first line indented by 2.55cm and the following lines aligned with the left of the page. Why is this - and how do I fix it?

Comment: Well, what you try to do doesn't sound like a good idea. Could you please post a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing what you have, and explain precisely what is your intention? Because I have a feeling that you're mis-using some of the concepts of LaTeX -- which happens quite often, but still, it's better to change it, isn't it? ;)

Comment: Do you want all lines in a paragraph indented like that?

Comment: @Sigur yes I do, I basically want every new line to be indented from the left by 2.55cm.

Comment: But only for a part of the document, right? I suggest you to adapt the `quote` environment.

Comment: Every new line?  and 2.55cm from left margin of the typeblock is?  `\parindent 2.55cm` (or: `\setlength{\parindent}{2.55cm}`) and start a new paragraph with each line.  Or this is in an environment..? Or do you mean every line in the output..?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the `changepage` package, one can locally adjust the margins of text in a page. To achieve this, we use the environment, `adjustwidth`.

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{<leftmargin>}{<rightmargin>}
<content>
\end{adjustwidth}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{2.5cm}{}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{adjustwidth}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```